# Why ajax call not responding integer type value?

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

This is my ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
     type: "get",
     url: "xyz",
     success: function(res){
        alert("hello");// not coming while returning int type but coming while returning a String value.
     }
});
```

In my controller,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/xyz")
@ResponseBody
public Integer xyz(){
    int i = 10;
    return i;
}
```

What is wrong here. Instead of int type if I am returning a String type i am able to get data in ajax success.

Thanks

Comment: when you send int type what will be the value of 'res' when you console it?  if you do get some response then check what is the type of response by typeof property.

Comment: @Prajwal If I am sending int type then success function is not executing at all. Then how to console it.

Comment: The AJAX response needs to be in following format: XML, HTML, or JSON. Integer is not valid form. I prefer you to use JSON by seeing requirement. Hope that helps

Comment: @Prajwal Then how its taking String data is string data comes under XML, HTML or JSON form.

Comment: String data is treated as plain text which is one of content type to be used

Comment: I tried identical code and it worked fine for me. If I had to guess, you aren't hitting your controller with your request. The config 'url: "xyz"' is is relative in this context. Make 100% sure you are hitting your controller. If you aren't the response would be a 404 and not call your success callback. Try providing an error callback and see what the error is. If it's a 404, you'll know your url is wrong.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianDesserich but url is hitting and if i am changing return type from Integer to String its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should mention the full HTTP URL. Let's say something like this:

`http://localhost:8080/your_webapp_name/xyz`

and not just: `xyz`

Second, if you want to send a GET HTTP request to the server, you should mention it under method, and not under type. Like this:

`method:"GET"`

Now, the success method within your Jquery Ajax **will always expect to accept text as a parameter**, so in your case, the `res` parameter should be treated as text.

So instead you can just to this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/xyz")
@ResponseBody
public String xyz(){
    return "10";
}
```

And on your ajax success method convert the String to Number type.

In JavaScript you don't have integers, you do have String, Number, Boolean, Arrays, Objects.